# New Theme @ Live Site

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, merchant

We have a Magento Site which is online. We want to change the theme. Is there any way to install a new theme, make changes on it, which it is visible only for us, and when it is ready to replace old with the new?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a development environment you can always add a second `website` to your installation, give it a random URL (don't use `/test/` or `/beta/`, everybody does that) and set it to `noindex,nofollow` under the `System > Configuration > Design` tab.

Now you have a website you can install your theme on, make changes and when the time comes to switch either copy the settings to the live `website` or inactivate the old one.

*Side note: Please consider a development server. It's the best way to do stuff like this*